# CDH5.4.2 spark can use HiveContent in spark-shell but can't open spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, hivecontext

I am using spark(standalone) of CDH5.4.2

After copying `hive-site.xml` to `$SPARK_HOME/conf`,i can query from hive in `spark-shell`,such as below:

> scala> val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);
>   hiveContext: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@6c6f3a15
>   scala> hiveContext.sql("show tables").show();

But when i open `spark-sql` ,it show wrong:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver
>    Failed to load main class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.
>
> You need to build Spark with -Phive and -Phive-thriftserver.

What is different between `spark-shell` and `spark-sql`? If spark of cdh don't support hive,why can i use `HiveConext`?

Comment: What exactly do you think the `spark-sql` command is supposed to do?!?

Comment: Spoiler: Cloudera explicitly states that the Spark **JDBC Thrift server** is not supported in CDH, so it's not surprising that you cannot start it.

Comment: Thank you so much ,I will carefully to read the official document.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera has a list of unsupported features here:

https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.6/spark-overview/topics/spark-unsupported-features.html

The Thrift server is not supported.

This is a copy of the list for 7.2.6:

- Apache Spark experimental features/APIs are not supported unless stated otherwise.
- Using the JDBC Datasource API to access Hive or Impala is not supported
- ADLS not supported for All Spark Components. Microsoft Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS) is a cloud-based filesystem that you can access through Spark applications. Spark with Kudu is not currently supported for ADLS data. (Hive on Spark is available for ADLS.)
- IPython / Jupyter notebooks is not supported. The IPython notebook system (renamed to Jupyter as of IPython 4.0) is not supported.
- Certain Spark Streaming features, such as the mapWithState method, are not supported.
- Thrift JDBC/ODBC server is not supported
- Spark SQL CLI is not supported
- GraphX is not supported
- SparkR is not supported
- Structured Streaming is supported, but the following features of it are not:
- Continuous processing, which is still experimental, is not supported.
- Stream static joins with HBase have not been tested and therefore are not supported.
- Spark cost-based optimizer (CBO) not supported.